# Confocal Parabolae. How many intersections?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

How many intersections can two confocal parabolas have? Can this be found out as a function of angle between the axes of the two parabolas? Also, what is the result in the case when the axes are perpendicular to each other?

I guessed the answer (two?) for the case in which the axes are inclined at $180°$, considering $y^2 = 4x$ and $y^2 = 8–4x$.

It'd be great if the solution could not only be mathematically rigourous but also based on properties of conics, and geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the common focus of the parabolae is $F$.  Let $P$ be a point of intersection of the two parabolae.  Then, by the geometry of parabolae, the distance from $F$ to $P$ is the same as the distance to either directrix (call them $d_1$ and $d_2$).

Recall that $P$ is equidistant to $d_1$ and $d_2$.  Observe that a point is equidistant from two lines if it lies on the of the angle-bisector lines of the lines' intersection.  Since the parabolae lie on one side of each directrix, there is one "quadrant" where the intersections can occur.

Therefore, the intersections lie on a single line, which can intersect to parabolae at most twice.  Moreover, any intersection of this angle bisector must correspond to an intersection of the two parabolae.

Comment: Understood this, thanks! I was just wondering if there existed some other relatively rigourous method (such as using their equations, etc.) to approach this question? Can it be solved in that manner? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As written, this can be made rigorous (since one way to define a parabola is as the set of points equidistant from a point and a line).  As for an algebraic solution, algebraically, there are at most four solutions, (and exactly four intersections if you look in complex projective space).  It will be hard to come up with a completely algebraic solution because most algebraic solutions will not be able to distinguish between real and complex points.